# renaming a sql server with installed named instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a hosted server that is named, by the hosting company, as something like WinEnt99. We would like to rename it to something more meaning like OurMonitor1.

We have already installed a few instances of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Is there anything that we need to (re)configure in SQL Server / SSMS ?

I have an application that was reading the database settings from the registry, and connecting the database fine. Now, it won't connect to the database. The only thing that I can think of is that we renamed the server last week sometime.

EDIT 02 Oct 2012:-
The Server is being renamed. The named instances are not.

I've run

```
sp_helpserver
select @@servername
```

Which showed the old server name,
and

```
sp_dropserver 'Old Server Name\Instance_name'
go
sp_addserver 'New Server Name\Instance Name','local'
go
```

Then confirmed the details in

```
sp_helpserver
select @@servername
```

Comment: This was cross-posted on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676627/renaming-a-sql-server-with-installed-named-instances

Answer (score 4):

You are only allowed to change the server name or hostname of a server running SQL server. Microsoft does not support renaming the instance without a reinstall. So if you have a default instance on the server that is referenced by the hostname you can rename the "instance" in that manner. However if you are wanting to go from "hostname\instance1" to "hostname\instance2" you will have to reinstall SQL Server.